# Question about call by value in C language

Tags: c, function, scope, global-variables, pass-by-value

When I run this program, it outputs `10 20` (first snippets of code).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 10;
int y = 20;

int main()
{
    fun(x, y);
    printf("%d %d", x, y);
}

int fun(int x, int y)
{
    x = 30;
    y = 40;
}
```

But when I write it as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 10;
int y = 20;

int main()
{
    fun(x, y);
    printf("%d %d", x, y);
}

int fun(int n1, int n2)    // I include other variables except from global variable.
{
    x = 30;
    y = 40;
}
```

it outputs `30 40`. I want to know why it modifies the global variables only second code snippets even though without using pointers? and why first one is not? if anyone suggest me reference for this theory part I would be great full.

I want to learn these theory parts correctly because I am new to programming.

Comment: shadowing. Its good to know about, but its even better to not use globals and not use same name for different variables

Comment: In your first program the local argument variable names *shadow* the global variables of the same name. When you assign to e.g. `x` you assign to the local argument variable. In the second program when you assign to `x` you assign to the global variable. In both programs you print the values of the global variables.

Comment: You have discovered one of the several reasons why global variables is a big no-no.

Comment: "even though without using pointers?" I don't see any pointers in your code.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In the first code snippet, the fun function receives the parameters x and y by value, which means that the function creates its own local copies of those variables. Any modifications made to these local copies do not affect the original global variables x and y defined outside the main function. Therefore, when you print x and y in the main function after calling fun, their values remain unchanged, resulting in "10 20" being printed.

In the second code snippet, you're using the same variable names x and y as the global variables inside the fun function. This creates ambiguity because the function parameters n1 and n2 have the same names as the global variables. In this case, when you assign values to x and y inside the fun function, it modifies the global variables themselves because they have the same name. This is called shadowing, where the local variables shadow the global variables with the same name. As a result, when you print x and y in the main function after calling fun, you see the modified values "30 40" because the global variables were directly modified within the function.

To avoid confusion and potential issues like this, it is generally recommended to use different names for local variables in functions to clearly distinguish them from global variables. This helps improve code readability and avoids unintentional modifications to global variables.

For further understanding of variable scope and shadowing, you can refer to C programming language textbooks or online resources that cover these topics in detail. Some recommended resources include "The C Programming Language" by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie or websites like tutorialspoint.com or cplusplus.com.

Comment: _"the function parameters n1 and n2 have the same names as the global variables"_ -- The function parameters in the second example have the names `n1` and `n2` and _do not shadow any global variables_. The shadowing is in the first example, not in the second. The first example creates local variables that shadow the globals and modifies only the locals; the second example modifies the global variables directly and doesn't even make use of the arguments passed to the function.

Comment: y ur right, thks for the correction

Comment: Since your answer is the accepted answer, you should strive to make it correct by editing. There are currently three other _correct_ answers here, none of which has been accepted by OP.

Answer (score 2):

For starters pay attention to that the function `fun` shall be declared before its usage within the body of `main`.

In the first function

```
int fun(int x, int y)
{
x = 30;
y = 40;
}
```

there are changed function parameters `x` and `y` that are local variables of the function. The parameters were initialized by values of the file scope global variables `x` and `y` but the global variables themselves were not changed.

Within the function the global variables `x` and `y` are hidden by the parameters with the same name. So the function deals with the parameters instead of the global variables.

You could use the following trick to change the global variables within the function

```
int fun(int x, int y)
{
    x = 30;
    y = 40;
    
    {
        extern int x;
        extern int y;

        x = 30;
        y = 40;
    }
}
```

In this case the declarations within the inner block of the function

```
extern int x;
extern int y;
```

refer to the global variables that have external linkage and the global variables are changed.

In the second function parameters are not used.

```
int fun(int n1, int n2)    // I include other variables except from global variable.
{
x = 30;
y = 40;
}
```

In such cases the compiler issues a message about unused parameters.

Within the function there are directly changed the global variables. The file scope variables `x` and `y` are visible and accessible in the body of the function.

You may consider the body of the second function the following way

```
int n1 = x;
int n2 = y;

x = 30;
y = 40;
```

Answer (score 1):

In first example you are modifying **local variables `x` and `y`** which are created as **parameters** to your function `fun`

In second example you are leaving those parameters alone and instead modifying the global variables `x` and `y`

If you wanted to modify parameters in the second example you would change

```
int fun(int n1, int n2)
{
    n1 = 30;
    n2 = 40;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have learned, function arguments are passed by value in C, so when calling `fun(x, y)` you pass the current values of the global variables `x` and `y` to function `fun`.

In the first example, function `fun` is defined with the names `x` and `y` for the function arguments. In the body of the function, when you refer to `x` and `y`, the argument definitions are in scope and modifying `x` and `y` only modifies the argument values, which are local to the function. The global variables are not affected.  When a local definition hides another one from an outer scope, we say that the outer definition is *shadowed* by the inner one.  This is somewhat confusing and error prone: passing `-Wall -Wextra` to the **gcc** or **clang** compilers will enable a warning for this case.

In the second example, the function arguments are defined as `n1` and `n2`, so the code in the function body does modify the global variables `x` and `y`, and indeed the program outputs the modified values.

Note also these remarks:

- the prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)` in C;
- the function `fun` should be declared or defined before use.  The compiler leniently accepts this call and infers the prototype from the function arguments as `int fun(int, int)` which is consistent with the later function definition.  This pre-ANSI behavior is supported for compatibility with old code, such as examples from the original K&R book, but modern C programs should not rely on this and the extra warning level will complain about it.
- the `main` function should return `0` for success, albeit C99 has made this the default behavior in absence of a `return` statement.
- you should output a trailing newline to ensure proper display in the terminal.  Without this newline, the shell prompt might appear glued to the last character output, causing further confusion, especially if the prompt is `%` or `$`.
- the function `fun` is defined as returning an `int`, but the function is exited without a `return` statement. You should define the function as `void` to avoid undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 10;
int y = 20;

void fun1(int x, int y) {
    x = 30;
    y = 40;
}

void fun2(int n1, int n2) {
    x = 30;
    y = 40;
}

int main(void) {
    fun1(x, y);
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y); // outputs 10 20
    fun2(x, y);
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y); // outputs 30 40
    return 0;
}
```